# Building in Release mode requires other project lib file but Debug mode doesn't

Tags: c++, visual-c++, release-mode

I've got two projects in a C++ project. Building in debug mode works fine however it fails in Release mode when linking. Essentially, it seems that each project requires the other's lib file (circular dependency)?

Is there a reason why this would only be an issue in relase mode? Perhaps optimisation?

What I'm doing:

Project A has base type ABase.
Project B has base type DerivedFromABase (which is derived from ABase). It includes ProjectA\ABase.h as a result. So project B has a dependency on project A.

In Project A, there is a file, Process.cpp. This file uses pointers to ABase, which can be of type ABase or DerivedFromABase (though all are cast as pointers to ABase).

If I include project B's DerivedFromABase.h in project A's Process.cpp, project A now seems to need project B's lib file, **but only in Release mode**. This happens even when never explicitly using the DerivedFromABase class. Debug mode compiles with no issues.

EDIT: I'm not necessarily interested in workarounds to get it to work. This was just a quick hack to test a new feature (these projects are two of many) - I'm in the process of refactoring the code to implement it properly, so that project A need not know about DerivedFromABase. I'm interested in why it works in Debug and not Release.

Comment: Go to project B properties and add dependancy for project A. You will see, that project A now compiles before project B. This should solve your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk4ahe0t(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx

Comment: @Satus, I can't do that as it'll create a circular dependency. Project A is earlier in the build order than project B and does compile correctly. It fails at link time when it trys to link to Project B's lib file.

Comment: Then you can extract one of the libs to another project (static lib).

Comment: A circular dependency can sneak in and go undetected for a while, surviving on existing .lib files from the previous build.  Until you Clean or need to build another configuration.   Use Build + Rebuild once a day.  Build servers are very good about reminding you about these kind of problems, recommended.

Comment: A clean/rebuild was the first thing I tried but unfortunately didn't resolve the issue. Rebuilt both configurations. Debug continued to work and release continued not to.